# CodeIgniter Loader extend causes error

Tags: codeigniter, utf-8, loader, extend, byte-order-mark

I've came across something that drives me crazy. please help me :(

I'm try to extend the CI_Loader Core in-order to create global header and footer.
For some reason, the extending causes error.

**The extend code:**

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // i need the codeigniter super-object 
        // in all the functions
        $CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function load_header()
    {
        echo 'header';
    }

    public function load_footer()
    {
        echo 'footer';
    }

}
```

**The error i currently get**

```
Unable to load the requested file: helpers/url_helper.php
```

**UPDATE: CHANGED THE CODE - NEW ERROR**

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load = $this;
    }

    public function load_header()
    {
        echo 'header';
    }

    public function load_footer()
    {
        echo 'footer';
    }

}
```

now i get some error with the header

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mounted-storage/home75b/sub007/sc43190-SREL/gogetmilk.com/application/core/MY_Loader.php:1)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 672
```

**UPDATE #2**
I'm not its the right way to fix it. but its working.

line 672 in libraries/Session.php sets a cookie

i've added a test to see if headers were already sent:

```
    if (! headers_sent() )
    {
        setcookie(
            $this->sess_cookie_name,
            $cookie_data,
            $expire,
            $this->cookie_path,
            $this->cookie_domain,
            $this->cookie_secure
        );           
    }
```

its not working ok.
i've created session before printing anything, after printing, within views, after loading views, etc..

does anyone believe this will cause any problems?

**problem solved and was not related to codeigniter. see answer at the bottom.**

Comment: btw, this error appears only when i run the code on a server. when i run it on localhost(zendserver) it works.. i guess its error displaying setting..

Comment: why are you doing $CI->load = $this; in your "Updated" code in __construct function??

Comment: Because this is an extension of the Loader. now i can load views and stuff inside like this: $this->view('view_file);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. it wasn't even a CodeIgniter Issue.

It was an invisble BOM at the begining of the file.
Used this application to remove this bytes: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bomremover/

Thanks everybody for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

> The error i currently get Unable to load the requested file:
>
> helpers/url_helper.php

You're getting this error because you didn't load URL helper. I don't see any call to any URL helper function so I assume the error is being thrown in another file ... Try adding

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

in relevant file or just load it in the `config/autoload.php`

and, yes, use parent::__construct(); as answered by Broncha

Answer (score 0):

Your construct should call the parent's construct

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // i need the codeigniter super-object 
    // in all the functions

    $CI =& get_instance();
}
```